Why does Pandas .floor() throw AmbiguousTimeError for this Timestamp that's already unambiguous?
The following fails:
def round_in_tz(epoch_sec: int, tz_name: str, freq_spec: str):
  """Round the given epoch timestamp to the nearest pandas time frequency spec in the given timezone."""
  return pd.to_datetime(epoch_sec, unit='s', utc=True).tz_convert(tz_name).floor(freq_spec)

print(round_in_tz(1730610000, "US/Eastern", freq_spec="86400s"))  # works OK
# raises pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from 2024-11-03 01:00:00, try using the 'ambiguous' argument
print(round_in_tz(1730610000, "US/Eastern", freq_spec="300s"))  


Is there truly any ambiguity here? I'm aware of DST, but using epoch times avoids any ambiguity, right? Is this a bug in Pandas?
What's the best way to rewrite it? I hacked together the following:

def round_in_tz(epoch_sec: int, tz_name: str, freq_spec: str):
  """Round the given epoch timestamp to the nearest pandas time frequency spec in the given timezone."""
    t = pd.to_datetime(epoch_sec, unit='s', utc=True).tz_convert(tz_name)
    is_dst = bool(t.timetuple().tm_isdst)
    return t.floor(freq_spec, ambiguous=is_dst)

NOTE: We cannot use .floor(freq_spec).tz_convert(tz_name) because it changes the behavior when freq_spec="86400s". (I want Midnight US/Eastern, not Midnight UTC.)
I've found several previous questions on DST ambiguity, but they all involve truly ambiguous situations (such as parsing a timestamp from a string during the doubly-occurring DST hour.) In contrast, this question uses the epoch timestamp 1730610000, which I would not expect to be ambiguous.

It'd help to write a better title, like say, "Why is Pandas .floor() saying this timestamp is ambiguous when it already has a UTC offset associated with it?" For tips, check out [ask].

Done, thx for the suggestion!

Welcome to the trip down the DST rabbit hole, many end up here.


Is there truly any ambiguity here? I'm aware of DST, but using epoch times avoids any ambiguity, right? Is this a bug in Pandas?


Yes, the epoch time itself is technically unambiguous, however the ambiguity happens once you want to convert it to a local time.
In your case, this is caused by how (DST) transitions are handled in the round_in_tz() function:

1730610000 falls on the November 3, 2024, when clocks are moved back to 1:00 AM, which means there are two instances of 1:00 AM in a single day
when you round with a high enough frequency (e.g. a whole day or "86400s"), this ambiguity is removed, since floor rounds down to the start of the day, which is clearly set
however when you round using a short enough frequency, one hour or less, (e.g. 5min or "300s"), the ambiguity remains, since it's not clear which instance of 1:00 AM you mean

You can test yourself, that your call to round_in_tz will work with "high enough" frequencies, e.g.:
# works just fine
print(round_in_tz(1730610000, "US/Eastern", freq_spec="43200s")) 



What's the best way to rewrite it? I hacked together the following:


Your hack is essentially correct. The best way to handle is to simply define how your code should behave in case it encounters an ambiguous time conversion. This can be done via the ambiguous argument of the floor() method, as you did. Using tm_isdst as you did is completely fine. Alternatively, you can setup ambiguous=True or ambiguous=False if you need/want, which will treat the ambiguous time as DST or standard respectively.

If you are interested in some further reading, this short post offers a decent summary of some epoch time limitations, including the ambiguity when converting to local time.
